# Create new relationships from the result of a query neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to build new relationships from the result of shortest path between a node and a set of nodes. I'm currently using this query to do such task but between two node (it works very well):

```
MATCH
  (p1:Category {catName: "Main_topic_classifications"}), 
  (p2:Category {catName: "Monarchs_of_the_Bulgars"}),
  path = allShortestPaths((p2)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]->(p1))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```

How can I generalize this query in order to return the list of allshortestPaths between p2 ("Monarchs_of_the_Bulgars") and a list of nodes p1 = ["Health", "History", "Humanity"] instead of one node like the previous query?

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
MATCH (p1:Category)
WHERE p1.category IN ["Health", "History", "Humanity"]
MATCH
  (p2:Category {catName: "Monarchs_of_the_Bulgars"}),
  path = allShortestPaths((p2)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]->(p1))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```

[UPDATED]

If `p1` must also be the immediate subcat of `Top_Main_Classification`, then you can do this:

```
MATCH (p1:Category)-[:SUBCAT_OF]->(main:Category {catName: "Main_topic_classifications"})
WHERE p1.category IN ["Health", "History", "Humanity"]
MERGE (p1)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(main)
MATCH
  (p2:Category {catName: "Monarchs_of_the_Bulgars"}),
  path = allShortestPaths((p2)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]->(p1))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help. Can I impose one more condition on the returned path where the top nodes (Health, history, etc.) must be connected to the top main classification node, i.e.,  (p1)-> (Top_Main_Classification)?

Comment: I modified my update to also create `NEW_SUBCAT` relationships between the `p1` nodes and the "main" node.